# Why would I choose a private read-only auto-property over a read-only field?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

An [article about changes in C# 6.0 at Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/csharp-the-new-and-improved-csharp-6-0) presents read-only auto-properties and claims (emphasis by myself):

> An interesting consequence of support for auto-property initializers is that it eliminates many of the cases found in earlier versions where you needed explicit field declarations. (...) On the other hand, the need to declare read-only fields becomes virtually deprecated. Now, whenever a read-only field is declared, **you can declare a read-only auto-property possibly as private**, if that level of encapsulation is required.

Why in the world would I do that?

I fully understand the benefits of exposting properties rather than fields, as this maintains binary compatibility even in cases where I need to add some validation code or similar in a later version. But what is the benefit of *always* having a private read-only property over a private read-only field?

*Please note that I am not asking about specific scenarios where a private read-only property has benefits over a private read-only field. The quoted article implies whenever a private read-only field could be used, one should opt for a private read-only property instead. Is there any tangible benefit from this, or was this just the author's enthusiasm about the new feature going overboard?*

Comment: Your quote has the answer: "**if** that level of encapsulation is required." - granted, that's subjective.

Comment: (Emphasis mine) "The quoted article implies whenever a private read-only field could be used, one **should** opt for a private read-only property instead" - no, it doesn't.

Comment: @Dai: Yes, it does: "whenever a read-only field is declared, you can declare a read-only auto-property" - doesn't it?

Comment: Methinks you're reading it wrong -- I interpret the author as saying a read-only field is no longer needed *as the backing field of a property*. They're not saying that *all* read-only fields (including those not backing properties) are suddenly obsolete. The stuff about private properties is just to remind you that those, too, are a thing. I grant you the way things are formulated is a little clumsy.

Comment: "you can" does not mean "you should" - those are **very different** semantics. [There's a whole IETF RFC that describes the differences](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2119) between "shall", "may", "must" and more.

Comment: @Dai: Well, sure, you *can* do a lot of things. You *can* store a text to a file and read it again later just for the fun of it, even if storing it in a simple string variable would be fully sufficient. However, clearly, articles like that one do not indulge in listing nonsensical detours. They point out what you *can* do because the author thinks it is what readers *should* do.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Well, the author says that *whenever* I have a read-only field, I can consider it as obsolete. Thus, I'm asking: Why should I do that *whenever* I have a read-only field, rather than just in *certain cases* where I have a read-only field? I'm confident the author did not mean *whenever*, but I'm afraid of missing something important in that text, hence my question :)

Comment: I disagree. I agree with @JeroenMostert in that the article's author is merely providing a suggestion, not a recommendation - let alone a blanket recommendation - to use auto-properties over direct field access.

Comment: @Dai agreed, the wording has "if required" after the suggestion. It doesn't say you *should*, it just says you **can**. Also *virtually deprecated* doesn't equal deprecated.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: the author says this in the explicit context of "eliminat[ing] many of the cases found in earlier versions where you needed explicit field declarations". If you think the author really meant that fields are now obsolete for all purposes and you want to know why, I suggest *asking the author* (Mark Michaelis), not the Internet. If Mark *was* arguing that all private fields should be replaced with properties, I'd disagree (for the record), but I don't think he says that.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: I do not think the author *meant* that it is a good idea to replace any private read-only field with a private read-only property, but I do suspect the author *unintentionally wrote* just that. No matter which one it was - I'm actually not so much interested in the personal views of the author, but in common practice and common knowledge among developers that I might, in this case, for some reason, be missing. If the response is "There does not appear to be a reasonable explanation for such a recommendation.", then that is a great answer (and actually the one I somewhat ...

Comment: ... expect), but I see no reason to get nitpicky about "can" vs. "should" when it is a technical article that clearly describes what I *can* do because it has some practical benefit, not just because the author baselessly felt like pointing out hypothetical options.

Comment: The way I read the article is "when you want to have a property (either public or private) with a readonly backing field, you now don't have to create a full property with explicit (readonly) backingfield, just create (and initialize) a get-only auto-property" - so "no field" is only about the case when you already want/have a property instead of a generic "never fields"

Comment: I suspect you already know very well that there hasn't been a surge of code bases where all private fields have been replaced with properties. :-P It's a Guy on the Internet Writing Stuff, MVP or not. He's not a language designer and this isn't a spec proposal. If he says stuff that looks silly (whether it *is* silly or because he's being misread), move on. You may safely assume your instincts for good code are not invalidated just because an MVP wrote something without elaborating. MVPs, too, need to back their arguments with facts or explicit experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replace the full context. This sentence is in the chapter [Primary Contructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/csharp-the-new-and-improved-csharp-6-0#primary-constructors). With primary constructors, it make sense to replace read-only backing field by [Auto-Property Initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/october/csharp-the-new-and-improved-csharp-6-0#auto-property-initializers).

I agree, this sentence is weird :

> Now, whenever a read-only field is declared, you can declare a read-only auto-property possibly as private, if that level of encapsulation is required.

When I read this, I see two axioms :

1. With primary constructor, you should use auto-property initializer instead of read-only backing field.
2. Hey guy, it's **possibly** to declare the property with auto initializer **private**

I think the author has favored brevity instead of readability or the author advocate to the end of field.

But the primary constructor isn't integrated in the final C#6 or next versions, so we still need backing field a long time.